# How to call a simple javascript function(); when I click on a button in a .swf file (FLASH)?

Tags: javascript, actionscript, flash, call

I click on a button (or any object where I can write Action Script) and It should call a javascript function which I wrote in my functions.js

Like an alert message for example.

How do I do this?

Comment: Have you, like, done *any* research at all?

Comment: `ExternalInterface.call("functionname","variables");`

Comment: @mgraph - stick it as an answer dude

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this `ExternalInterface.call("functionname","variables");`